# Ascii code and unicode are destroyed in ollydbg

Tags: ascii, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I'm Studying basic step of reverse engineering. The program is simple that pop up string "Hello world!", using MessageBox() API. Practice work is find "Hello world" in a dump window and change that string into "Hello Reversing!".

I found a main method, and succeeded find adress where the "Hello string' located. But I think ASCII code is wrong.

There will be show string "H.e.l.l.o..W.o.r.l.d.!.." I think. But it doesn't
Is there any error on ASCII code? or something I missed it?

[ascii and unicode is weired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDYzl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't find the string, obviously. Addresses in Dump and Disassembly windows reveal that you are looking at the same place in memory and this memory contains the code that calls MessageBox, not its string arguments.

You need to follow one of its operand in dump to find the string you are looking.